# Python Pandas hypostesis: average rating for the "expensive" books. Need some help understatding the basic features of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm studying pandas now and having issues in understanding of basic features. I'm exploring this [data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jwLv0kqvszA73trrb939bUTjD0fT4rnH/view?usp=sharing). There's a variable "Price (Above Average)" that contains "Yes" if the price of the book is greater than the average, and "No" if it is less.

I assumed that a book's rating is independent of its price and want to test it. Now I need graphing the average user rating for each of the groups.

At first I want to print the average rating for the "expensive" books just to figure out how it works. I don't understand the syntax very well yet, so I'm hoping on your help.

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish your stated task? What specific issue are you facing in your attempt?

Comment: @shorn I need to determine the average rating for cheap and expensive books. That's what I want to find out in result but I wanted to figure this out myself after answering this question

Comment: But you see, to us it looks like you haven't done ANYTHING on your own.  This is not a tutorial site.  You need to make a good effort to solve your problem on your own.

Comment: Hey, nice training project. You might want to consider using True and False instead of Yes and No. The latter are strings and might be slightly more cumbersome to handle in bigger projects. (E.g. 'if df['high price']: *function*)

Comment: @Sumerechny, thanks for the tip! Yeah, booleans are more stable espesially if I need only two values. Will use it if I'll make similar variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the average rating for the books:

```
df['average_rating_for_books'] = df.groupby(['Price (Above Average)'])['User Rating (Round)'].transform('mean')
```

After this, you can filter out books which are expensive.

To filter out rows, you can write a function like:

```
df[df['Price (Above Average)'] == 'Yes']
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data is in df:

```
   df.groupby("Price (Above Average)").agg(avg_raiting=("User Rating", "mean"))
```

The `groupby` function groups your data by each of the different values in the column you pass, in this case, "Price (Above Average)".

The `agg` function aggregates a column over the groups created in the `groupby`. Here, you are creating a new column named `avg_raiting` using the column "User Rating", and calculating the "mean".

This will show you the average rating for the "expensive" books and others.